# HTML URL Path Rewriting

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, mamp

I am running static HTML files on a local MAMP server and I would like to pass an ID to a page (user.html) in the 'URL Path' format. Here's what I need it to look like:

> http://localhost:8888/mysite/user/3245653/john

- user is the html page. I removed the .html extension from the url by using .htaccess rules
- the number after the user/ is the ID parameter
- john is another parameter I need to add to the url

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Currently the URL looks like this:

> http://localhost:8888/mysite/user

So I could send parameters as Query strings using `?id=` but I need to use the Path format

What is the change I need to make to create that URL Format?

Comment: Downvoter explain and why did you vote to close it?

Comment: Any specific reason why you tagged this with firebase-hosting? It seems unrelated to that, so I'm going to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add new rewrite rules to pass additional parameters to your pages:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.html?id=$1&name=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.html?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now the CSS isn't being read properly. Should I be changing the path of the CSS?

Comment: Also bro what if I want to have `users/234/john` for the user page but `products/24342` format for the products page? So basically in the products page, there's only 1 parameter and 2 parameters for user page

Comment: Yes I do. So 2 pages but with 2 different URL formats

Comment: Still the CSS and JS 404 issue persists mate. It can't seem to find the css files after rewriting url

Comment: ok for css/js add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/mysite/" />`

Comment: Works like a charm. I don't know why someone voted down the question haha. Thanks bro

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted but I voted up to neutralise that.